# Extract Ruby Parameters

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, rack, middleware

Hi i am trying to make a rack controller similar to `Rack::URLBuilder` but i am having trouble extracting the parameters.

`config.ru`

```
run Example::Controller.new ([
  "test" => Sinatra::Application
])
```

`controller.rb`

```
module Example
  class Controller

    def initialize(map = {})
      @map = map
    end

    def call(env)
      puts @map
    end

  end
end
```

This code puts out:

`testSinatra::Application`

every time i run the app. How can i extract one value as test and another value as `Sinatra::Application`

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? Earlier versions would print a hash's key and value adjacent to each other, like `testSinatra::Application`, but 1.9.3 prints `{"test"=>Sinatra::Application}`. Nevertheless, your code _is_ returning a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It often helps to add a `.inspect` when you are experimenting and putting in debug traces etc:

```
puts @map.inspect
```

this gives you a better debug output than the default string conversions on a lot of classes.

You should see that the data you want is in fact there.

Comment: Thank you for this i was able to see that there was in fact data in the hash